# Android: What are the correct arguments for a simple adapter?

Tags: android, listview, android-adapter

I am unable to get my List View to display anything within it. It is created properly but both the items and sub items are blank. How to i resolve this?

Are the arguments that I have used within the adapter correct?

```
SimpleAdapter adapter = new SimpleAdapter(this, list, android.R.layout.simple_list_item_2, keys, ids);
```

Activity with List view:

```
@Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

        setContentView(R.layout.results);

        ListView itemList = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.lvresults);

        //gets array from prev act
        int[] results = getIntent().getIntArrayExtra("results");

        int numberPassed = getIntent().getIntExtra("numberPassed", 0);


        ArrayList < HashMap <String, String> > list = new ArrayList < HashMap <String, String> > ();


        // loop to give list view
        for (int i = 1; i <= 12; ++i)
        {
            int userAnswer = results[i - 1];

            int expectedAnswer = numberPassed * i;

            String userString = numberPassed + "x" + i + "=" + userAnswer;

            String expectedString = "" + expectedAnswer;

            HashMap <String, String> map = new HashMap <String, String> ();

            map.put("user", userString);
            map.put("expected", expectedString);

            list.add(map);
        }


        String[] keys = {"user", "expected"};

        int[] ids = {R.id.user_answer, R.id.expected_answer};

        SimpleAdapter adapter = new SimpleAdapter(this, list, android.R.layout.simple_list_item_2, keys, ids);

        itemList.setAdapter(adapter);
    }
}
```

Comment: Check your keys properly if its right or not.

Answer (score 0):

You are using `android.R.layout.simple_list_item_2` as your row layout. It isn't going to have fields with those ids. You should replace that with your own layout id.